# Keyboard shortcut to kill a script containing multiple wgets?

Tags: bash, shell, python, wget

I have a Python script that wgets a load of files:

```
for year in range(2010, 2015):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        filename = url
        filename += "/T%s%s_BNFT.CSV" % (year, month)
        os.system('wget %s' % filename)
```

I am running this on a remote server, running it in the background with `python script_name.py &`.

If I need to kill this script half-way through, I try using `Ctrl+X, Ctrl+C` but it only seems to kill the current wget (and not at all if the wget is already under way). I have to hit  `Ctrl+X, Ctrl+C` 20 or 30 times to kill the script.

I can also open a new session and do `ps aux | grep script_name.py` and then `kill <pid>` to kill the script. But opening a new session itime-consuming and painful.

Is there any easier way to kill the background script, using keyboard shortcuts? Alternatively, is there any way I can run `ps aux` from the current session?

Comment: Take a look at [How do I capture SIGINT in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1112343/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to achieve this with a keyboard shortcut easily.

However, since your running the script in the background could you not just run something like

```
kill $( ps aux | grep '[s]cript_name' | awk '{ print $2 }' );
```

In the current session?

Could make it easier by placing that in a shell script called kill_script_name